# What is the prefered way to setup a read only github account for servers

Tags: github, deployment

I had 2 github accounts setup for my organisation, the main account "software" and an account "servers" that I used only on our servers to pull updates (and switch branches)

They were both personal accounts, "Software" was a paid account "Servers" was a free account.

This setup has been working fine, but we've now had to convert "Software" into an organisation account. I did this and created read and write teams for our repositories then invited the appropriate people.

That all went well.

But now I can't invite the "servers" account, so I can no longer use that one to pull updates to our staging & production servers. I assume that the issue is that this is a free account.

It seems to work, in that I can find the account and create an invite, but nothing comes up on the "Servers" account when I login, and no email is sent.

I don't see the point in setting up a paid account, as it will never be used to create or contribute to a repository. It will only ever be used on our servers to pull updates.

I also don't want to use my own account on the servers as that seems like a pretty bad practice.

So what is the best practice for pulling updates to servers?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [deployment keys](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/) instead of creating virtual accounts and inviting servers. It's a common setup if you need to pull changes only. That's what deployment keys are made for.

Comment: I thought they could only be used for one repository each though. I can't think of a way to setup my ssh config to allow me to do "git pull" and specify which key to use.

Comment: So you are using machine users? https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#machine-users

Comment: At the moment yes, I've managed to add them as contributors to the repos now. So maybe that's what I'll have to stick with.